# Saving list of Bitmap Images

Tags: c#, uwp, file-storage

I have a list of Bitmap images. I need to save them to local folder. 
This doesn't work on windows 10 Universal application.

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<BitmapImage>));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)) {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, collection);
        }
```

WriteObject method throws the following error

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' in System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" - What error are you getting?

Comment: Kindly see the edited question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapImage` is not serializable. Convert that to a byte array and write that to disk instead:

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
        btmMap.SaveJpeg(ms, bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)) {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, ConvertToBytes(collection));
    }
```

Comment: how to convert back the bytes to Bitmap image?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract the bitmap from a [`BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage). There is no way to save a `BitmapImage` to file directly. The only way is to remember the original source and save that out. For more details about save `BitmapImage` to file please reference [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d246f4d2-3aed-4115-a85a-646c0d617d67/saving-bitmapimage-to-file?forum=winappswithcsharp).

If you know the original source, for example, you read the `BitmapImage` from the file picked by a `FileOpenPicker`, then you can read the image file to a [`WriteableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap) then you can extract the [`PixelBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_WriteableBitmap_PixelBuffer), encode it with a [`BitmapEncoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder), and then save the resulting stream to a `StorageFile` as Rob said. Sample code as follows:

```
private async void btncreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    StorageFile originalimage = await openpicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    WriteableBitmap writeableimage1;
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await originalimage.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
        writeableimage1 = new WriteableBitmap(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
        writeableimage1.SetSource(stream);
    }
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile newimage = await folder.CreateFileAsync(originalimage.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (IRandomAccessStream ras = await newimage.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, ras);
        var stream = writeableimage1.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)writeableimage1.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableimage1.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, buffer);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

For list of images, you may need save them one by one.